# one callback for two async function, one is google api getDistanceMatrix

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to create a function that executes two async actions simultaneously. One is a simple AJAX request, and the second is for getDistanceMatrix from the google maps API. The point is that I want to have a single callback function that uses the data from both of the functions. I am familiar with the JQUERY function $.when(), but I could only use It when dealing with two AJAX functions, but not with the google API. This is the code that I am trying to get to work. a1 is fine, but a2 is undefined.

```
function getLocation(){
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService()
    var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(32.07989,34.813026);
    var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(32.08989,34.813026);
    return  service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [origin],
        destinations: [destination],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING ,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
    })
}
function getFriends(){
    return $.ajax({
        data: "&action=get_friends"
    });
$.when( getLocation(),getFriends()).done(function(a2,a1){
        alert(a1)
        alert(a2)
    });
}
```

My guess is that google maps API just don't return any value, but I would like to find a solution that doesn't involve complicated patterns.
Thanks for your time,
Daniel

Comment: You are calling `$.when(getLocation(), getFriends())...` _inside_ the `getFriends()` function, after it has returned. If this is your actual code posted, that would likely be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own `$.Deferred` instance for the `service.getDistanceMatrix()` callback:

```
function getLocation(){
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService()
    var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(32.07989,34.813026);
    var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(32.08989,34.813026);
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [origin],
        destinations: [destination],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING ,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
    }, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
          deferred.resolve(response);
        } else {
          deferred.reject(status);
        }
    })
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

This `getLocation()` function would return a deferred promise that you can use in `$.when()`.

Comment: Yes, I like this solution - and it fixes the issue that I had in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `service.getDistanceMatrix` call doesn't return data as a result of the call, but instead calls a callback function with the results:

From https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix :

> A successful call to the Distance Matrix service returns a DistanceMatrixResponse object and a DistanceMatrixStatus object. These are passed to the callback function you specified in the request.

you probably need to provide a callback that will return the response object to your deferred:

```
function getLocation(){
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService()
    var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(32.07989,34.813026);
    var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(32.08989,34.813026);
    return  service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [origin],
        destinations: [destination],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING ,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
    }, myCallback) // add callback here
}
function getFriends(){
    return $.ajax({
        data: "&action=get_friends"
    });
$.when( getLocation(),getFriends()).done(function(a2,a1){
        alert(a1)
        alert(a2)
    });
}
// declare the callback function
function myCallback(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    return response;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you think `myCallback()` is returning `response` to?

Comment: Hm, good point. I assumed the response would be returned to the 'return' statement of 'getLocation' - but thinking about that further, that's probably not the case.

Comment: The `return` statement of the `getLocation()` function has long been executed at the point where `myCallback()` is called.